# Create responsive circular arc on mobile screen

Tags: html, css

I want to create something like this:

[image]

I have a few questions regarding as to how to go about this:

1. Creating concentric circular arc(donut) : Should I create a full circle which is clipped by the screen border or is there a better way?
2. Placing the circles for dynamic screen sizes.

Comment: What have you tried previously? Do you have any code for poeple who might want to help you to work from?